# civix generate:module org.civicrm.angularex error

Tags: drupal, civicrm-buildkit, civix

lteI have installed a civicrm buildkit with vagrantbox and vagrant up correctly on windows, ubuntu server run and at d7-master.dev I am listening drupal civicrm all done ok.

as I try to generate module using civix extension builder such as:

in cmd:

```
civix generate:module org.civicrm.angularex
```

I got this error: [RuntimeException] Failed to determine INI file path.

I tried everything what I knew and what see by google nothing happens.such as :

```
php --ini
```

works but not resolve this error.

Please Help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [**set** the appropriate environment variable](https://superuser.com/a/1218436/445903):

1. close your current cmd shell/terminal;
2. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `setx CV_CONFIG "%userprofile%\.cv.json"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
3. reopen the shell, goto your project's directory and test with `civix civicrm:ping -vvv`.

I gave further explanations about the reason in [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18988/4741).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,
realized the module was actually created but with incomplete information in the "info.xml" file in the module.
Updated the content of the file and activated the extension from `Administer --> system settings --> extension`