# Civicrm:ping INI file not found

Tags: error, civix, windows

I have installed civicrm and want to develop an extension.
I installed civix for creating this extension but when i run `civix civicrm:ping` command in my civicrm folder, I get the following error:

`C:\xamp\htdocs\civicrm>civix civicrm:ping`

> [RuntimeException]
>
> **Failed to determine INI file path**.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is CiviCRM working in your browser? Did you install CiviCRM with civicrm-buildkit, or manually? What CMS are you using?

Comment: Yes it's working on my local host. Using Drupal. didn't install any buildkit, will do that on cent os server.

Answer (score 4):

I was just dealing with this and found your question..

Since you used `C:\`, i'll assume you're in windows.

**TLDR;** Try checking your PHP environment variable for 'HOMEPATH' vs 'HOME' and editing the file I mention below.

The first thing I will say is that you can increase verbosity of errors in civix by using `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` options for most verbose. It helped me a lot with this issue.

I will leave the important details of my environment here as well, for others who may find this question:

A working Drupal 7 + CiviCRM 4.7.17 locally installed (manually) with MAMP on a Windows 10 machine, configured to use PHP 5.6.28. MAMP is installed to `C:/MAMP` and the site root is `C:/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/`

Civix is installed to `C:/Users/"Eli Lisseck"/` and I am seeing the same behavior as you that civicrm:ping throws and exception.

Running the more verbose command `civix civicrm:ping -vvv` led me to the file `C:\Users\Eli Lisseck\civix\vendor\civicrm\cv\src\Config.php` line 54.

Check if it is looking for your HOME environment variable correctly, versus what you have under environment variables when you run `php -i`. I found it was only looking for 'HOME' but what existed was 'HOMEPATH'... so I added at line 52:

```
elseif (getenv('HOMEPATH')) {
      $file = getenv('HOMEPATH') . '/.cv.json';
      return $file;
    }
```

Now I get `civix civicrm:ping Ping successful`

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

I was about to take Eli's approach, but then I realized it is much simpler:

1. close your current cmd shell/terminal;
2. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `setx CV_CONFIG "%userprofile%\.cv.json"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
3. reopen the shell, goto your project's directory and test with `civix civicrm:ping -vvv`.

Alternatively, if you prefer to check/set environment variables for your account, **run**:

- `%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl EditEnvironmentVariables`

## Why?

If you notice `civix\vendor\civicrm\cv\src\Config.php@getFileName()`, the first environment variable that it expects is `CV_CONFIG`, and when it doesn't find it, it will try `getenv('HOME') . '/.cv.json'`.

Therefore, you can either set the new variable I mentioned above or just:

- `setx HOME %userprofile%`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut to Eli's answer; just `civix civicrm:ping -vvv` and check for ...`\civix\vendor\civicrm\cv\src\Config.php`. If you find it, it means you need to change `HOME` to `HOMEPATH`.

From

```
elseif (getenv('HOME')) {
  return getenv('HOME') . '/.cv.json';
}
```

to

```
elseif (getenv('HOMEPATH')) {
  return getenv('HOMEPATH') . '/.cv.json';
}
```